# Update query which doesn't allow date ranges in other records

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres a record contains startdate, enddate and other fields. When updating a record it should not allow record with already existing dates. I need a query for updating a record which doesn't allow duplicate records

Comment: How does your table look like? what sample data it contains? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share what you have tried so for and the problems that you are facing so that someone can help in resolving them.

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE t 
(
    pid INTEGER,
    aid INTEGER,
    startdate DATE,
    enddate DATE
) ;


WITH data_to_insert (pid, aid, startdate, enddate) AS
(
    VALUES (1, 1, date '2017-01-01', date '2017-01-31')
)
INSERT INTO 
    t (pid, aid, startdate, enddate)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    data_to_insert
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT * 
    FROM t 
        JOIN data_to_insert 
            ON (t.startdate, t.enddate) 
            OVERLAPS (data_to_insert.startdate, data_to_insert.enddate)
    ) ;
```

Or, using your variables (which should be `sanitized` to avoid SQL injection):

```
INSERT INTO 
    t (pid, aid, startdate, enddate)
VALUES
    ($prjid, $allocid, date $stdate, date $enddate)
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT * 
    FROM t 
        JOIN data_to_insert 
            ON (t.startdate, t.enddate) 
            OVERLAPS (date $stdate, date $enddate)
    ) ;
```